# Angular Language Service Extension not working in Visual Studio 2019 with Angular 12

Tags: angular, visual-studio

Microsoft Visual Studio Enterprise 2019 (Ent) Version 16.10.4

Angular 12.1.14 project.

“devDependencies”: {
“@angular-devkit/build-angular”: “~12.1.4”,
“@angular/cli”: “~12.1.4”,
“@angular/compiler-cli”: “~12.1.0”,

I just uninstalled and then reinstalled the `Angular Language Service Extension` and I still get this error:

`“There was an error activating the remote language server, Angular Language Service Extension. Please select Help > Send Feedback > Report a Problem…”`

This error pops up as soon as I introduce an error in a file (such as declaring a variable without a type).

I'm not having the problem with Angular 10 projects, haven't tested with Angular 11.

I'm not interested in using VS Code so please don't suggest it.

Once the error shows up VS 2019 keeps hanging up and often crashes making the extension unusable. I have uninstalled it at this point.

I have not been able to find any info on the internet and MS developer community for VS has not been of any help.

Has anyone else come across this problem?  Any possible resolutions or is there a bug in the extension or Angular 12?